# Is there a way to generate unique IDs based on attribute values in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<sections>
 <sec id="1" sid="1">....</sec>
 <sec id="2" sid="2">....</sec>
 <sec id="3" sid="1">....</sec>
 <sec id="4" sid="1">....</sec>
 <sec id="5" sid="2">....</sec>
</sections>

<sec-list>
  <s ref="1">.....</s>
  <s ref="2">.....</s>
  <s ref="3">.....</s>
</sec-list>
```

When parsing the `sec-list` in XSLT, I want to detect all `sections/sec[@sid=@ref]` and provide anchor tags pointing to each single one. E.g: for `sec-list/s[@ref="1"]` I want to show 3 anchor tags pointing to the 3 `sec` nodes having `@sid="1"`:

```
<div id="?">sec with id=1 and sid=1</div>
<div id="?">sec with id=3 and sid=1</div>
<div id="?">sec with id=4 and sid=1</div>




<a href="#?">sec with id=1 and sid=1</a>
<a href="#?">sec with id=3 and sid=1</a>
<a href="#?">sec with id=4 and sid=1</a>
```

I need to replace the '?' with a unique id that I can later use in the 'href' to point to.

Comment: How "static" do the references need to be? Could you just use line numbers?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `generate-id()` function to generate unique IDs, even in XSLT-1.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="sec-list/s" mode="div"  />
    ### Delimiter ###
    <xsl:apply-templates select="sec-list/s" mode="href" />
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="sec-list/s" mode="div">
    <xsl:variable name="ref" select="@ref" />
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/sections/sec[@sid=$ref]">
        <div><xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="generate-id()" /></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="concat('sec with id=',@id,' and sid=',$ref)" /></div>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sec-list/s" mode="href">
    <xsl:variable name="ref" select="@ref" />
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/sections/sec[@sid=$ref]">
        <a><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="concat('#',generate-id())" /></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="concat('sec with id=',@id,' and sid=',$ref)" /></a>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is:

```
<div id="idm3">sec with id=1 and sid=1</div>
<div id="idm5">sec with id=3 and sid=1</div>
<div id="idm6">sec with id=4 and sid=1</div>
<div id="idm4">sec with id=2 and sid=2</div>
<div id="idm7">sec with id=5 and sid=2</div>
###################
<a href="#idm3">sec with id=1 and sid=1</a>
<a href="#idm5">sec with id=3 and sid=1</a>
<a href="#idm6">sec with id=4 and sid=1</a>
<a href="#idm4">sec with id=2 and sid=2</a>
<a href="#idm7">sec with id=5 and sid=2</a>
```

Notes:

- I used the variable `$ref` instead of `current()/@ref` because the value is also used in the `concat(..)` expression.
- The IDs `#idmX` refer to the `sections/sec` elements.
- The above templates assume that `<sections>` and `<sec-list>` elements are wrapped in a root element called `<root>`.